# JQgrid empty field search

Tags: search, filter, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

[Empty Field Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5pqp.png)I have a grid which holds the data from a json file. I want to filter particular column which may have empty value too.See the image where packageName has empty fields. I need to filter that rows on clicking a button. I am posting the filters for PostData as empty value which is "". But now the grid is fetching all the data from it. I need to do this filter on my grid. Any help ??

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried ?

Comment: Reddy.....pls have a look at this post where i have place my code.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839238/jqgrid-custom-searching-or-filtering

Answer (score 0):

1. create a hidden column(such as colA2) for empty.
2. set empty value as "(blank)" to colA2.
3. Search colA2