# JQgrid custom searching or filtering

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

[Image for My JQgrid with my Own filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C14y.png)

```js
/**
 *
 */
var grid = jQuery("#list2");
var keyitems = [];
var valitems = [];
var uniqueNames = [];
var colNamesHeader = [];
var filterobjArr = [];
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {



      $('body').click(function(e) {
        var isInpOpen = $("#dialogInp").dialog("isOpen");
        if (isInpOpen && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'INPUT' && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'IMG' && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'DIV')
          $("#dialogInp").dialog("close");
        var isCheckOpen = $("#dialogCheck").dialog("isOpen");
        if (isCheckOpen && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'INPUT' && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'IMG' && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'DIV')
          $("#dialogCheck").dialog("close");
        var isDateOpen = $("#dialogDate").dialog("isOpen");
        if (isDateOpen && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'INPUT' && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'IMG' && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'DIV' && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'SELECT' && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'A' && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'SPAN')
          $("#dialogDate").dialog("close");
      });

      $("#dialogInp").dialog({
        height: 45,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
      });
      $("#dialogCheck").dialog({
        height: 'auto',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
      });
      $("#dialogDate").dialog({
        height: 'auto',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
      });
      var myControl = {
        create: function(tp_inst, obj, unit, val, min, max, step) {
          $('<input class="ui-timepicker-input" value="' + val + '" style="width:50%">')
            .appendTo(obj)
            .spinner({
              min: min,
              max: max,
              step: step,
              change: function(e, ui) { // key events
                // don't call if api was used and not key press
                if (e.originalEvent !== undefined)
                  tp_inst._onTimeChange();
                tp_inst._onSelectHandler();
              },
              spin: function(e, ui) { // spin events
                tp_inst.control.value(tp_inst, obj, unit, ui.value);
                tp_inst._onTimeChange();
                tp_inst._onSelectHandler();
              }
            });
          return obj;
        },
        options: function(tp_inst, obj, unit, opts, val) {
          if (typeof(opts) == 'string' && val !== undefined)
            return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').spinner(opts, val);
          return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').spinner(opts);
        },
        value: function(tp_inst, obj, unit, val) {
          if (val !== undefined)
            return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').spinner('value', val);
          return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').spinner('value');
        }
      };
      $("#from").datetimepicker({
        controlType: myControl,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showTime: false,
        showMin: false,
        showHour: true,
        hourText: "Time",
        minuteText: "",
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        timeFormat: "hh:mm",
        closeText: "Cancel",
        buttonText: "Select date",
        currentText: "Today",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "assets/images/cal.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        pick12HourFormat: false,
        onSelect: function(time, inst) {}
      });
      $('#to').datetimepicker({
        controlType: myControl,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showTime: false,
        showMin: false,
        showHour: true,
        hourText: "Time",
        minuteText: "",
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        timeFormat: "hh:mm",
        closeText: "Cancel",
        buttonText: "Select date",
        currentText: "Today",
        showOn: "button",
        pick12HourFormat: false,
        buttonImage: "assets/images/cal.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function(time, inst) {}
      });
      $('.searchRem').click(function(e) {
        var colIdInp = $("#dialogInp").data("id");
        var colIdCheck = $("#dialogCheck").data("id");
        var colIdDate = $("#dialogDate").data("id");
        var isInpOpen = $("#dialogInp").dialog("isOpen");
        var isCheckOpen = $("#dialogCheck").dialog("isOpen");
        var isDateOpen = $("#dialogDate").dialog("isOpen");
        if (isInpOpen) {
          colIdCheck = '';
          colIdDate = '';
          if (this.src.indexOf('search') > -1) {
            var enteredSearch = $(this).closest('div.ui-dialog').find("input[type='text']").val();
            filterGrid(enteredSearch, colIdInp);
          } else if (this.src.indexOf('remove') > -1) {
            filterGrid('', colIdInp);
          }
        }
        if (isCheckOpen) {
          colIdInp = '';
          colIdDate = '';
          if (this.src.indexOf('search') > -1) {

            if (colIdCheck == 'colorcode' || colIdCheck == 'event') {

              var checkboxes = $(this).closest('div.ui-dialog').find("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
              var checkArr = []
              for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                checkArr.push(checkboxes[i].nextSibling.textContent);
              }
              filterGridCheck(checkArr, colIdCheck);
            } else {

            }
          } else if (this.src.indexOf('remove') > -1) {
            filterGridCheck('', colIdCheck);
          }
        }
        if (isDateOpen) {
          colIdCheck = '';
          colIdInp = '';
          if (this.src.indexOf('search') > -1) {
            if (colIdDate == 'currentdate') {
              var fromSearch = $(this).closest('div.ui-dialog').find("input[type='text']")[0].value;
              var toSearch = $(this).closest('div.ui-dialog').find("input[type='text']")[1].value;
              filterGridDate(fromSearch, toSearch, colIdDate);
            } else {

            }
          } else if (this.src.indexOf('remove') > -1) {
            filterGrid('', colIdDate);
          }
        }
        grid[0].p.search = fi.rules.length > 0;
        $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, {
          filters: JSON.stringify(fi)
        });
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{
          page: 1
        }]);
        $("#dialogInp").dialog("close");
        $("#dialogCheck").dialog("close");
        $("#dialogDate").dialog("close");
      });
      var valArr = function() {
        return ':Select All;3:3;5:5';
      }

      /*parse json from file*/

      $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "js/grid.json",
        // data: data,
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
          //console.log(typeof data);
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
              $.each(val, function(key, val) {
                keyitems.push(key);
                valitems.push(val);

              });
            });
          }
          $.each(keyitems, function(i, el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
          });

          colNamesHeader.push('');
          colNamesHeader.push('');
          var ColModel1 = [];
          ColModel1.push({
            name: 'radio',
            index: 'radio',
            width: 15,
            align: 'center',
            sortable: false,
            search: false,
            formatter: function(cellValue, option) {
              return '<input type="radio" name="radio_' + option.gid + '" />';
            }
          });
          for (var i = 0; i < uniqueNames.length; i++) {

            colNamesHeader.push('<img id="filter' + uniqueNames[i] + '" class="ui-grid-custom-filter" alt="Filter" src="assets/images/no_filter_icon.png"/><span class="ui-grid-custom-header">' + uniqueNames[i] + '</span>');
            ColModel1.push({
              name: uniqueNames[i],
              index: uniqueNames[i],
              align: 'center',
              width: 30,
              search: false
            });

          }
          jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
            //url:'js/grid.json',
            datatype: "local",
            data: data,
            //colNames:['','<img class="ui-grid-custom-filter" alt="Filter" src="assets/images/no_filter_icon.png"/><span class="ui-grid-custom-header">packageNumber</span>','<img class="ui-grid-custom-filter" alt="Filter" src="assets/images/no_filter_icon.png"/><span class="ui-grid-custom-header">packageName</span>', '<img class="ui-grid-custom-filter" alt="Filter" src="assets/images/no_filter_icon.png"/><span class="ui-grid-custom-header">packageData</span>', '<img class="ui-grid-custom-filter" alt="Filter" src="assets/images/no_filter_icon.png"/><span class="ui-grid-custom-header">event</span>','<img class="ui-grid-custom-filter" alt="Filter" src="assets/images/no_filter_icon.png"/><span class="ui-grid-custom-header">currentdate</span>','<img class="ui-grid-custom-filter" alt="Filter" src="assets/images/no_filter_icon.png"/><span class="ui-grid-custom-header">colorcode</span>','<img class="ui-grid-custom-filter" alt="Filter" src="assets/images/no_filter_icon.png"/><span class="ui-grid-custom-header">initiator</span>'],
            colNames: colNamesHeader,
            //          colModel:ColModel1,
            colModel: [{
              name: 'radio',
              index: 'radio',
              width: 50,
              sortable: false,
              search: false,
              resizable: false,
              formatter: function(cellValue, option) {
                return '<input type="radio" name="radio_' + option.gid + '" />';
              }
            }, {
              name: 'text',
              index: 'text',
              width: 100,
              sortable: false,
              search: false,
              resizable: false,
              formatter: function(cellValue, option) {
                return '<input type="text" class="myText" name="text_' + option.gid + '" />';
              }
            }, {
              name: 'packageNumber',
              index: 'packageNumber',
              width: 150,
              "sorttype": "int",
              formatter: 'showlink',
              formatoptions: {
                baseLinkUrl: 'Combobox.jsp',
                addParam: '&menuindex=1',
                idName: 'packageNumber'
              }
            }, {
              name: 'packageName',
              index: 'packageName',
              width: 120,
              "sorttype": "string"
            }, {
              name: 'packageData',
              index: 'packageData',
              width: 150,
              "sorttype": "string"
            }, {
              name: 'event',
              index: 'event',
              width: 80,
              align: "right",
              "sorttype": "string"
            }, {
              name: 'currentdate',
              index: 'currentdate',
              width: 150,
              align: "center",
              sorttype: 'date',
              formatter: 'date',
              formatoptions: {
                newformat: 'd-M-Y H:i',
                srcformat: 'd-M-Y H:i'
              },
              datefmt: 'd-M-Y H:i',
              searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
                dataInit: initDateSearch
              }
            }, {
              name: 'colorcode',
              index: 'colorcode',
              width: 120,
              align: "right",
              formatter: 'select',
              edittype: 'select',
              editoptions: {
                value: '3:3;5:5',
                defaultValue: 'Intime'
              },
              stype: 'select',
              searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne'],
                value: valArr
              }
            }, {
              name: 'initiator',
              index: 'initiator',
              width: 150,
              "sorttype": "string"
            }, {
              name: 'owner',
              index: 'owner',
              width: 150,
              "sorttype": "string"
            }, {
              name: 'assignee',
              index: 'assignee',
              width: 150,
              "sorttype": "string"
            }],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#pager2',
            sortname: 'packageNumber',
            viewrecords: true,
            autowidth: true,
            loadonce: true, // to enable client side sorting
            sortorder: "asc",
            "width": "1320",
            "height": "150",
            sortable: {
              options: {
                items: ">th:not(:has(#jqgh_list2_cb,#jqgh_list2_radio,#jqgh_list2_rn,#jqgh_list2_text),:hidden)"
              }
            },
            multiSort: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            multiselect: true,
            multiboxonly: true,
            //       multiGroup:true,
            viewsortcols: [true, "vertical", true],
            height: '150',
            caption: "Item Record",
            //        altRows:true,
            loadComplete: function() {
              var filter = grid[0].p.postData.filters,
                f, rules, rule;
              if (typeof filter !== "undefined") {
                f = JSON.parse(filter);
                rules = f.rules;
                for (i = 0, l = rules.length; i < l; i++) {
                  rule = rules[i];
                  if (rule.op === "eq") { //rule.data:"1"
                    if (rule.data === "1") {
                      $("#cb_" + rule.field).attr("checked", "checked");
                    } else {
                      $("#cb_" + rule.field).removeAttr("checked");
                    }
                  }
                }
              }

            },

          });
          jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', {
            edit: false,
            add: false,
            del: false,
            search: false
          }, {}, {}, {}, {
            multipleSearch: true,
            multipleGroup: true,
            showQuery: true
          });
          grid.setCaption('Item Records&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '<input type="button" id="btn_test"  onclick="alert(11);" value="Open" />');

          //$('#list2').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOnEnter: true, enableClear: true});
          //$(".ui-search-toolbar").hide()

          $(".ui-jqgrid img").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var colorli = '',
              eventli = '';
            if (this.parentElement.textContent == 'colorcode' || this.parentElement.textContent == 'event') {
              if (this.parentElement.textContent == 'colorcode') {
                var colorcodedata = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
                colorcodeUnique = $.map(colorcodedata, function(item) {
                  return item.colorcode;
                });
                colorcodeUnique = colorcodeUnique.filter(function(itm, i, colorcodeUnique) {
                  return i == colorcodeUnique.indexOf(itm);
                });


                for (var i = 0; i < colorcodeUnique.length; i++) {
                  colorli = colorli + "<li><input type='checkbox'/>" + colorcodeUnique[i] + "</li>";
                }
                $('#listPrep').html("");
                $('#listPrep').html(colorli);
              } else {
                var eventdata = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
                eventUnique = $.map(eventdata, function(item) {
                  return item.event;
                });
                eventUnique = eventUnique.filter(function(itm, i, eventUnique) {
                  return i == eventUnique.indexOf(itm);
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < eventUnique.length; i++) {
                  eventli = eventli + "<li><input type='checkbox'/>" + eventUnique[i] + "</li>";
                }
                $('#listPrep').html("");
                $('#listPrep').html(eventli);
              }

              $("#dialogCheck").data("id", this.parentElement.textContent);
              $("#dialogCheck").dialog("open");
              $("#dialogCheck").dialog("option", "position", {
                my: "left top",
                at: "left bottom",
                of: this.parentNode
              });
            } else if (this.parentElement.textContent == 'currentdate') {
              $("#dialogDate").data("id", this.parentElement.textContent);
              $("#dialogDate").dialog("open");
            } else {

              $("#dialogInp").data("id", this.parentElement.textContent);
              $("#dialogInp").dialog("open");
              $("#dialogInp").dialog("option", "position", {
                my: "left top",
                at: "left bottom",
                of: this.parentNode
              });
            }

            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
          });

        },
        error: function() {
          alert(1);
        }
      });

      initDateSearch = function(elem) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(elem).datetimepicker({
            controlType: myControl,
            showDropPanel: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showTime: false,
            showMin: false,
            showHour: true,
            hourText: "Time",
            minuteText: "",
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
            timeFormat: "hh:mm",
            closeText: "Cancel",
            buttonText: "Select date",
            currentText: "Today",
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "assets/images/cal.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            onClose: function() {
              if (this.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  jQuery("#list2")[0].triggerToolbar();
                }, 50);
              } else {
                // to refresh the filter
                $(this).trigger('change');
              }
            },

          });
          $(".ui-datepicker").draggable({
            containment: "window"
          })
        }, 100);

      }


      //  Prepare to pass a new search filter to our jqGrid
      var fi = {
        groupOp: "AND",
        rules: []
      };

      function filterGrid(str, colId) {
        //  Prepare to pass a new search filter to our jqGrid
        var f = {
          groupOp: "AND",
          rules: []
        };
        //  Remember to change the following line to reflect the jqGrid column you want to search for your string in


        if (str !== '') {
          f.rules.push({
            field: colId,
            op: "cn",
            data: str
          });
          fi.rules.push({
            field: colId,
            op: "cn",
            data: str
          });
          $('#filter' + colId)[0].src = 'assets/images/filter_icon.png';
        } else {
          //             str=str.trim();
          //             fi.rules.push({ field: colId, op: "cn", data: str });
          fi.rules = fi.rules
            .filter(function(el) {
              return el.field !== colId;
            });
          $('#filter' + colId)[0].src = 'assets/images/no_filter_icon.png';
        }
        grid[0].p.search = f.rules.length > 0;
        $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, {
          filters: JSON.stringify(f)
        });
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{
          page: 1
        }]);

      }

      function filterGridCheck(strArr, colId) {
        //  Prepare to pass a new search filter to our jqGrid
        var f = {
          groupOp: "OR",
          rules: []
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {

          //  Remember to change the following line to reflect the jqGrid column you want to search for your string in
          f.rules.push({
            field: colId,
            op: "eq",
            data: strArr[i]
          });
          fi.rules.push({
            field: colId,
            op: "eq",
            data: strArr[i]
          });

        }
        if (strArr.length == 0) {
          fi.rules = fi.rules
            .filter(function(el) {
              return el.field !== colId;
            });
        }
        grid[0].p.search = f.rules.length > 0;
        $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, {
          filters: JSON.stringify(f)
        });
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{
          page: 1
        }]);
        if (strArr.length > 0) {
          $('#filter' + colId)[0].src = 'assets/images/filter_icon.png';
        } else {
          $('#filter' + colId)[0].src = 'assets/images/no_filter_icon.png';
        }
      }

      function filterGridDate(from, to, colId) {
        //  Prepare to pass a new search filter to our jqGrid
        var f = {
          groupOp: "AND",
          rules: []
        };
        f.rules.push({
          field: colId,
          op: "ge",
          data: from
        }, {
          field: colId,
          op: "le",
          data: to
        });
        fi.rules.push({
          field: colId,
          op: "ge",
          data: from
        }, {
          field: colId,
          op: "le",
          data: to
        });
        grid[0].p.search = f.rules.length > 0;
        $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, {
          filters: JSON.stringify(f)
        });
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{
          page: 1
        }]);
      }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html >
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- The jQuery library is a prerequisite for all jqSuite products -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the Javascript file of jqGrid -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="js/jquery.treegrid.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the localization file of the grid controlling messages, labels, etc.
    <!-- We support more than 40 localizations -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqgrid-init.js"></script>

    <!-- A link to a jQuery UI ThemeRoller theme, more than 22 built-in and many more custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/dateTimePicker.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" />

    <!-- The link to the CSS that the grid needs -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="assets/css/jquery.treegrid.css" />
    <!-- Our javascript  -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jqTreeGrid - Load On Demand - Load all Rows at once collapsed</title>
   
  </head>

  <body>

    <table id="tree"></table>
    <table id="tree1"></table>
   
    <div id="pager"></div>
    <!-- pager is not enacled for treegrid in jqgrid -->
    <table id="list2"></table>
    <div id="pager2"></div>
    <button id='mySearch'>Click me to Search</button>
    <div id='dialogInp' title="Dialog Title">
      <div>
        <input type='text' />
        <img src='assets/images/search.png' class='searchRem' />
        <img src='assets/images/remove.png' class='searchRem' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='dialogCheck' title="Dialog Title">
      <div>
        <input type='text' />
        <img src='assets/images/search.png' class='searchRem' />
        <img src='assets/images/remove.png' class='searchRem' />
        <ul id='listPrep'>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='dialogDate' title="Dialog Title">
      <div style="float: left; width: 80%">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>From</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id='from' type="text" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>To</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id='to' type="text" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <label>Blank Records</label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div style="float: right; width: 20%">
        <img src='assets/images/search.png' class='searchRem' />
        <img src='assets/images/remove.png' class='searchRem' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     
       
       
    </script>


  </body>

  </html>
```

I want to filter a date field in my grid where i can give from and to dates and post that data to the grid for reloading. so that i would get the data in between them...here serchrem is the buttom on which i will perform search..just like search button...The look and feel of my date Filter is attached in the image. Take a look at it.

Comment: You should post the JavaScript code to both of your last questions together with simple test data which can be used to reproduce the problem. The best would be to create the demo in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for example, which reproduces the problem. Moreover it's important to know which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: @Oleg...thanks for your speedy response...I have my code posted above..Look the properties for list2 for grid...$(.ui-jqgrid img).click for type of filter and searchRem.click for filter functionality...I am using Guriddo jqgrid JS only.Sorry its a little messed up....Please bear it as I am new to jqgrid...Help needed badly...

Comment: Oleg---As you requested .i am posting the fiddle here::::https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/

Comment: If you want to use Echo service of JFSiddle then you should use `url: "/echo/json/", data: { json: JSON.stringify(data) },` parameters in the $.ajax call. You wrote that you use Guriddo. Which version? You used in the demo jqGrid 6 instead. Which jqGrid you use really?

Comment: /**
*
* @license Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.1.0 - 2016-03-15
* Copyright(c) 2008, Tony Tomov, tony@trirand.com
* 
* License: http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334
*/ This is the actual jqgrid version i am using

Comment: I have updated the fiddle ..still it is saying length of colnames and colmodel are different. Can you see this here :https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/3/

Comment: Sorry, but your demo still not working. It seems to me that 90% of the code which you post have no direct relation to your question. What I see: you create the grid with `datatype: "local"` (is it so in your real code???) and the column `currentdate` which have `sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat: 'd-M-Y H:i',srcformat: 'd-M-Y H:i'}, datefmt: 'd-M-Y H:i', ...` and the input data in format like `"currentdate": "06-Apr-2015 05:06"` and you use English locale. Then you call `filterGridDate` with some values (which one???) of `from` and `to` parameter. Is it so?

Comment: The choice of language and locale dependent format of the date (`"06-Apr-2015 05:06"`) is bad, but it should still work.Really important is `datatype`, which you use, version of jqGrid which you use and the values of `from` and `to` parameters, which you use to call `filterGridDate` function. You could create jqGrid with 2-3 columns and call of `filterGridDate` with some example data without any unneeded plugins. You can use Echo service `/echo/json/` *as `url` parameter of jqGrid* and `postData` instead of `data` to simulate effects with `datatype: "json", loadonce: true`

Comment: Moreover you still not described clear enough your main problem. What is not working in your code? Do you get an error? Is nothing be filtered or an empty grid will be displayed after the filtering?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/4/.  Can you look at this sample now. Check for currentdate field and click on search ..U will get a dialog..give proper inpurts, Click on "sea".... Now the method 'filterGridDate' is called, where i am preparing filter data and triggering the reload of the grid. Here in that dialog i have a check box for blank records .. for this also. i need to filter the grid if it has any blank date field. Help me with that as well..which i have raised as an other question.Sorry for the messup so far

Comment: you mean something like https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/adgptkvj/6/ (I used `data` parameter instead of `addRowData`)? The example have no blank records. Could you provide the code which more close to your problem? Moreover I still don't understand why you use old jqGrid 4.6 and searching dialog. You could just call `filterGridDate` directly with some fixed values if the user clicks on "Search" button. If jqGrid will filter the data in the wrong way the you'll get already the example, which reproduces your original problem. Isn't so?

Comment: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa2.htm) for example. It use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.2 (the fork of jqGrid which I develop). The grid displays fillted data initialy. If you click on Reload button you will see all the data. You will find *empty* data. Then you can filter for date, for example "not equal" `01-Sep-2015`. You will see that the row with the empty date will be correctly displayed. One can read in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Custom-filtering-searching-Operation) more...

Comment: I got the solution for my date filter through your fiddle..@Oleg. By the way my working grid.js version is 5.1 which i took it from guriddo.net... Now my one prob is solved ie; date filter.I am calling my own function only right on click of search button. There only I am showing the dialog box based on type of data. I am searching dialog only here as my client need it that way @Oleg... .. .How to get empty search ? I am posting my fiddle here :  https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/7/ .... For the status I want both text search and empty search (fetching empty status rows .Here 2 rows)

Comment: @Oleg...http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa2.htm ..the demo u have shown has a empty field ..but how to search that empty field.. What is the search criterion?

Comment: Just empty string: "" is the string is really empty (your data). See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/adgptkvj/8/. If the property is `undefined` or `null` the you should include the corresponding searching operation. I posted you already that free jqGrid allow to define **custom** searching operation (described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Custom-filtering-searching-Operation)) and implement **any behavior what you need**. For example [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/DatetimeSearch1.htm) search for date ignoring the time. You can filter by `4/15/2015`

Comment: See [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/turkishInsensitiveSearch.htm) created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29415927/315935).

Comment: Super @Oleg...I am able to figure it out. Another issue exists, Sometimes during sorting. Sortname, sortOrder is coming undefined for me. The issue is repeating after two clicks which is(desc..asc....undefined.....)... I tried with code from one of ur response  using on  'jqGridSortCol 'and found this issue.

Comment: Sorry, but if you have an issue then **you should prepare the demo, which reproduce the problem**. One will see whether it's the problem in your code or the problem (a bug) in jqGrid. If It's free jqGrid then I'll fix the bug and publish fixed version on GitHub.

Comment: One more thing ..Can I make multi sorting only when user clicks on sort icons not on the whole header. and can i added a number to that icons saying 1,2,3...

Comment: @Oleg...I tried this fiddle..which replicates my sorting undefined issue. take a look at it pls. ::: https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/10/

Comment: @Oleg...Did you found the issue and any solution regarding these?

Comment: How to reproduce the "sorting undefined issue" on the demo? I see only the bug with the usage undefined `fi` variable in your code (search for `grid[0].p.search = fi.rules.length > 0;`). Moreover I wrote you that the version and the for of jqGrid which you use is important. You continue the usage of jqGrid 4.6 in the demo and writing that you plan to stay on Guriddo jqGrid. I can#T help you with Guriddo.

Comment: Try sorting any column two times . u will get alerts about sorting column. After two clicks u can see the data in the alert  undefined and " " (empty) .this is the same fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/adgptkvj/10/

Comment: I see only "" empty string as the 3-d state of the sorting. It's the feature. Without the feature one will be not able to "unsort" some column. For example, the user click the first, the second and the 3-d column headers to sort by the three columns. Lather one want to sort by the 4-th and the second columns only. It would be impossible if `multiSort: true` would be not support three state sorting. By the way free jqGrid can be configured to free-state sorting mode by adding `threeStateSort: true` option.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg for your inputs sofar. can u provide a sample with threeStateSort: true in freejqgrid with a fiddle.

Comment: Look at https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/5w5h2Lgw/7/ for example. The grid is sorted by `invdate` in `desc` initially. The first click will change the order to  `desc`, the second click will remove sorting and the data will be displayed in the order in which input data are provided. You can easy see this in the text from the first (Client) column. See [the get started documentation](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#sorting)

Comment: Now I understood ...three state sorting behaviour. Is it possible to achieve the way i requested ie; multi and single sorting in the same grid. Refer this question for full question:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979962/jqgrid-multisorting-along-with-single-sorting

Comment: Sorry, but it's very simple to formulate any exotic behavior. I just not understand the goal of it. If you need to provide the interface for the user where he can display the grid in unsorted state then `threeStateSort: true` option is enough. The user can display the grid in any required order. No user should set new requirement to application which he use: "I'd like that the click here do this thing and the click here - another thing". The interface defined the software and the user defined only the requirement: to be able to change the sorting order in 3-states.